How to make content fetched during login persist even if the user logs out and logs in again?
I currently am working on a project where a user authenticates, and when they are redirected to the home page, a GET request to an API is made:
def home(request):
    url = f'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/'
    headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json"
    } #Putting the application/json in the header to get a JSON result
    r = requests.get(url,headers=headers) #Making a get request to get a random dad joke
    data = r.json() #Converting JSON data to a python dictionary
    required_joke = {'joke': data['joke']}
    return render(request,'test_section/Home.html',required_joke)

Now, I mainly have two requirements:

When the user presses the refresh button, a new joke should be generated (satisfied).
If the user logs out, and logs back in again, the same joke that was being shown on the screen previously should be shown.

For example, if the user logs out now, and logs back in, he should see this same joke displayed.

I will be very grateful if someone can guide me regarding how to tackle this. It looks simple but I do not understand where to start.

Store the last joke in the Database. Have a landing page for immediately after a login which pulls the last joke from the database and displays it if the user logged in less than 10 seconds ago.
Rough cut (not checking this). Model
MAX_JOKE_LEN = 200 # or whatever
class Lastjoke( models.Model)
     user = models.Foreignkey( User, models.CASCADE, related_name='joke')
     text = models.CharField( max_length= MAX_JOKE_LEN)

Your Home page view
import datetime

def home(request):

    # has this user just logged in?
    user = request.user
    seconds = 1000000
    data = None
    if user:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        ago = now - user.last_login    
        seconds = ago.seconds + ago.days * 3600 * 24
    if seconds < 10:   # user logged in less than 10 seconds ago
        lastjoke = user.joke.last()
        if lastjoke:   # new user doesn't yet have one
            data = { 'joke': lastjoke.text }

    # if data exists it contains a last joke for a just-logged-in user
    if not data:

        url = f'https://icanhazdadjoke.com/'
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        } #Putting the application/json in the header to get a JSON result
        r = requests.get(url,headers=headers) #Making a get request to get a random dad joke
        data = r.json() #Converting JSON data to a python dictionary

    required_joke = {'joke': data['joke']}

    # remember the last joke which is about to be displayed 
    # purists will complain that a GET should not alter a database...

    if lastjoke:  # it exists so update it
        lastjoke.text = data['joke']
        lastjoke.save()
    elif user:
        Lastjoke.objects.create( user=user, text = data['joke'] )

    return render(request,'test_section/Home.html',required_joke)


The user can login and logout as many times as they want, but the joke will stay there until they press the refresh button. In a case like this, do I just set the 10 in seconds<10  to some big value? like 86400, or 86400*30?

No, 10 seconds since last login  is the definition of a just-logged-in user who gets the last joke. Otherwise they get a new one. Which is saved so if they then log out and in again they see the same one again.
